# How to turn off all other music when my Android app is playing music?

Tags: android, ios, audio

I was wondering how to exactly stop all other music that may be playing when my app is opened whenever there is music being played in my application. I have a couple instances where I just have sound effects, so is there anyway I can stop music that may be playing already whenever these sound effects pop up? I know I'm not giving any code, however, I have no idea how to approach this and haven't found many other questions asking similar things.Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the AudioManager.requestAudioFocus API.  Remember to release the focus when you're done with it, or other apps may not be able to play sounds correctly.